# What is the minimum required for a Resolution to be passed?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

I've been wondering what the minimum number of votes required to pass a resolution. Is there a minimum number of votes? Is it a percent of all the votes? 51% Majority and 50% votes cast? How do abstaining and Nay's factor into a vote?

I want to understand how many votes I need to fully control the world congress if I add my votes and a friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There must be as least one more *yay* vote than there are *nay* votes for a resolution to pass. Abstaining from voting on a particular resolution has no effect on the outcome as you are not voting either way.

In order to know how many delegates to commit you must make an educated guess about the votes of your rivals. You can place a Spy as a Diplomat in a rival's capital to see their upcoming votes.

Comment: No minimum number of votes?

Comment: I don't believe so. You should be able to pass it with a single *yay* vote as long as there are no *nays.*

Comment: you are correct there are no minimum, as voting on against or for a issue can have a political affect on your opponents. I have had the venitians declare they will vote against me in upcoming issues because i caused a resolution to not pass.

Answer (score 4):

For normal World Congress resolutions, the vote is a simple majority vote. If there is 1 more "yea" than "nay", then the vote passes.

The "World Leader" resolution is the only exception (Diplomatic Victory). This requires a minimum number of votes that is set based on the number of Civilizations and City States in the game (according to the in-game Civilopedia, and my experience). However the World Leader vote will not happen until the United Nations is built (and periodically afterwards), and cannot be manually initiated.